# E138: Can't write viminfo file $HOME/.viminfo

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, opensuse

I am using opensuse for my production environment.
I am login as "test" user and trying to edit a file using "vi" but when i am going to save
that file it shows the following error

**

> E138: Can't write viminfo file /home/test/.viminfo

**

Under the "test" user all the files and folder autometically become read-only.
I am trying to change the permission using "root" user but unable to change it.
also I look for temp file like "~/.viminf*" but there nothing like this.

Don't know what to do plaese help....
anyone aware about this problem

Answer (score 19):

Fix your home directory owner and permissions.

```
sudo chown -R test /home/test

sudo chmod u+rw -R /home/test
```

And finally check that no old temp files were left behind (e.g. ~/.viminf*) and that you can write in the directory of the .viminfo file.

Comment: its not wroking, it shows

pstscos341:/home/sibuild # sudo chown sibuild /home/sibuild/jira_certificate.        sath.com


chown: changing ownership of `/home/sibuild/jira_certificate.sath.com': Read-only file system

Comment: pstscos341:/home/sibuild # sudo chmod +urw /home/sibuild/jira_certificate.sath.com chmod: invalid mode: `+urw' Try `chmod --help' for more information.

Comment: Just edited the answer. Don't use sudo if you are trying this in root shell '#'

Comment: still not working...same error

Comment: It looks that the file /home/sibuild/jira_certificate.sath.com is currently in-use and you cannot change its permission. What is this file used for?

Comment: it used for nothing....I just keep this file here

Comment: Simply issue the following on Ubuntu or Debian >> sudo chown user:group /home/user/.viminfo changes the file permission to be owned by the current users using vim as @MohammedHabib said

Comment: `rm ~/.viminf?.tmp` worked for me - I had one for each letter of the alphabet